# What is python behavior when loading 'too large' data, or not having enough resources (either CPU or memory)?

Tags: python, for-loop, large-data

I am working on a program that at some point has a `for` loop over lists, some of them small, some of them huge (500k + elements).
When the application runs for some time, it comes systematically a time when it fails in this loop, while it did not fail at previous iterations, with smaller lists.

To debug, and using `pickle` module, I dumped the list before entering the function.
When the application fails, the list that has just been dumped is systematically a large one (500k+ elements).
File that is obtained is 70MB or more (binary mode).

I know I have spare RAM (using `htop`, I see I use approximately 400MB over 2GB available).
But CPU is frequently at a high percent of activity (more than 60%, sometime reaching 100%).

When I load the list from the file, (application is stopped) I can run the `for` iteration without trouble. The list does not appear corrupted.

So, I have absolutely no clue what can be wrong, except maybe CPU activity is high. If indeed Python has not enough resources to work, is there any way that it tells me so? How can I check this? What is its behavior? Is it possible the program stops without any error message?

### Edit - Code sample

Please find here below the code where the app freezes.
The code in itself executes normally.
The context of execution seems to be what makes the code freezing.

I could pinpoint that the app freezes at the start of the `for` loop named 'Bermuda Triangle'.
I can print the data with the `pickle` module, but I cannot get the print made within the for loop.
What is really weird is that I get the file supposed to get the print, but this file (`dump_loop.txt`) is empty.
I find this weird because either I should have 0 file (notice the `os.remove` at the beginning of the loop meaning I remove it systematically at each iteration) or if I have one, there should be something written in it.

I confirm that when the app runs (i.e. 'normally', it is not frozen), these two files are correctly updated.

Thanks for any help!
Bests,

```py
import os
import json
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('1599324732926-0',
         {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324732.767, \
                "receipt_timestamp":1599324732.9256856,\
                "delta":true, \
                "bid":{"338.9":0.06482,"338.67":3.95535}, \
                "ask":{"339.12":2.47578,"339.13":6.43172} \
               }'
         }),
        ('1599324732926-1',
         {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324732.767, \
                "receipt_timestamp":1599324732.9256856,\
                "delta":true, \
                "bid":{"338.9":0.06482,"338.67":3.95535}, \
                "ask":{"339.12":2.47578,"339.13":6.43172} \
               }'
         })]

         
def book_flatten(book: dict, timestamp: float, receipt_timestamp: float, delta: str) -> dict:
    """
    Takes book and returns a list of dict, where each element in the list
    is a dictionary with a single row of book data.

    """
    ret = []
    for side in ('bid', 'ask'):
        for price, data in book[side].items():
            ret.append({'side': side, 'price': price, 'size': data, 'timestamp': timestamp, 'receipt_timestamp': receipt_timestamp, 'delta': delta})
    return ret
         
def read(data, dtype='l2_book', pair='AAPL-USD'):       
    key = f'{dtype}-{pair}'
    if len(data) == 0:
        return []
    print("{!s}: Read {!s} messages from Redis".format(key, len(data)))
    ret = []
    ids=dict()
    last_id=defaultdict(list)

    # 1/Start - Lines added for debug
    # Retrieve the last data before the app freezes
    dump_list='./dump_list.data'
    try:
        os.remove(dump_list)
    except OSError:
        pass
    with open(dump_list, 'wb') as filehandle:
        # store the data as binary data stream
        pickle.dump(data, filehandle)
    dump_loop = './dump_loop.txt'
    total_number = len(data)
    counter=1
    # 1/End

    # The mysterious loop aka Bermuda Triangle
    for update_id, update in data:
        #2/Start - Lines added for debug
        try:
            os.remove(dump_loop)
        except OSError:
            pass
        with open(dump_loop, 'w') as filehandle:
            filehandle.write('Starting new loop for item {!s} over {!s}.\n'.format(counter, total_number))
        #2/End
        if dtype in {'l2_book'}:
            update = json.loads(update['data'])
            update = book_flatten(update, update['timestamp'], update['receipt_timestamp'], update['delta'])
            for u in update:
                for k in ('size', 'amount', 'price', 'timestamp', 'receipt_timestamp'):
                    if k in u:
                        u[k] = float(u[k])
            ret.extend(update)
        elif dtype in {'trades'}:
            for k in ('size', 'amount', 'price', 'timestamp', 'receipt_timestamp', 'bid', 'ask'):
                if k in update:
                    update[k] = float(update[k])
            ret.append(update)
        ids[key] = update_id
        #3/Start - Lines added for debug
        with open(dump_loop, 'a') as filehandle:
            filehandle.write('Loop finished.\n')  
        counter+=1
        #3/End

    last_id[key] = ids[key][-1]
    return ids, last_id, ret
```

Comment: When “it fails” there must be an error message - please edit the full error message into your question.

Comment: The thing is there is no error message. It just "freezes".
Inside this for loop, I have added "write" statements to track the exact point in the for loop when the application fails. But nothing get written when it fails.

Comment: It is 'as if' the problematic statement was the for x in my_list itself, that gets troublesome because the list is huge (compared to the CPU ressource available)? Is this possible?

Comment: Which for loop? Please create a [mre] and edit it into your question. Without this your question is ‘my code which I’m not showing you doesn’t work what’s the problem’ Which doesn’t have an answer except ‘there’s a problem with your code’

Comment: you could use `print()` to display values in variable and see which part is executed - this way you may see when it freeze. You can also save information in file but don't keep file open all time because it will save it when it freeze - close file after every write and reopen it before next write. If you don't have to use all data at the same time then maybe you should read data partially to memory - for example `pandas` can read data from csv in chunks and it can works only with part of data in memory.

Comment: @barny Hi, I added the 'mysterious loop' where the code seemingly freezes. The code itself runs ok, except in some circumstances I would like to be able to understand to avoid them. Or maybe at least detecting them to warn the user why the app freezes.

Comment: @furas Hi, thanks for trying to help. I cannot use print, because this for loop is executed sometime for 500k + elements. Sometime the freeze occurs after 10 minutes since the app started, sometime 2 hours (meanwhile, this for loop is run thousand of times every 10 minutes). So I am dumping in a file that is getting rewritten at every iteration. But this file is empty when the troublesome iteration happens. I am kinda lost.

Comment: @barny it’s pointless to badger the OP for minimum reproducible code example, or for error messages, in this class of problem.  By its nature neither is applicable.  I’ve had Python choke, reproducibly, 2 times in years of coding.  The error cause was never clear but it only appeared in the full program and with the full data.  Not sure how answerable this Q is here but dogmatic requests to adhere to std SO norms are besides the point.

Comment: You’re implying the OP’s code and information about the error is irrelevant to answering their question - clearly that’s not correct. Assumptions of all types can blind anyone to the reality of what’s happening, and everything’s even blinder if the OP doesn’t provide information that’s all part of understanding the problem. You may prefer to assume you know what’s going on is inscrutable - I prefer to ask for information. It was the OP’s choice to ask for help here - so how can there be anything wrong with asking them to provide information about their problem.

Comment: I'm not implying anything.  I'm saying that in these kinds of problems it is often very hard to separate out a small bit of code and data to make it reproducible.  Something you seem to fail to recognize, while providing little actual help.   Look at what they found - an OS-triggered cutoff due to too much memory - do you honestly think you'll get a memory-out error out *any* amount of data you'll post here???  do you think you'll get an error message?  This is not a bad question by itself, even if it *is* fishing, if I have something similar going on again, I'll check syslog.

Comment: Hey ho. Vive la difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,
So I was suggested to have a look at syslog (being quite a newbie, I did not know about this) and 'voilà'!
After a new test, the app `my_app` crashed at 17:45.
Here is what syslog says at 17:45:

```sh
Sep  6 17:45:12 cs1 kernel: [67093.681124] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-32.scope,task=cryp>
Sep  6 17:45:12 cs1 kernel: [67093.681180] Out of memory: Killed process 15754 (my_app) total-vm:1752588kB, anon-rss:1332040kB, file-rss:32kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:3144kB oom_sco>
Sep  6 17:45:12 cs1 kernel: [67093.764851] oom_reaper: reaped process 15754 (my_app), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

So no wonder python is not telling me anything, its process is killed...